# Rails omniauth and devise trouble with vk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, vk

I'm going to implement facebook and vkontakte login(registering) for my rails app, and with facebook all is ok (login and regitering is ok), done as in manual 
[here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

But with vkontakte something wrong, i'll still get "empty" page

here is my code:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def vkontakte
    @user = User.find_for_vkontakte_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Vkontakte"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.vkontakte_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

And model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable #:confirmable, 

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid, :name
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                           provider:auth.provider,
                           uid:auth.uid,
                           email:auth.info.email,
                           password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                           )
    end
    user
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
      if data = session["devise.vkontakte_data"] && session["devise.vkontakte_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end



  def self.find_for_vkontakte_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(name:auth.info.name,
                           provider:auth.provider,
                           uid:auth.uid,
                           email:auth.extra.raw_info.domain+'@vk.com',
                           password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                           )
    end
    user
  end
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried omniauth railscasts made by Ryan Bates ?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication - here is for facebook

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

these are for authentication from different social networks. I'm started working with VK api, so if you will have problems with implmentation of these railscasts - tell me.

Answer (score 1):

check if your server host as like registered in vk. For development, you may edit /etc/hosts and access to your site via this host.

Example: site is inmyhouse.su

/etc/hosts: 127.0.1.1   local.inmyhouse.su